# Windows 10 automatically changing ownership of external drive

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, file-permissions, ownership

An external disk used at work and at home is presenting a weird behavior. When plugged in on office computer, the user on that computer takes ownership of that disk and when is plugged at home, it can be opened (Access is denied).

So I have to take ownership of the disk in order to do access files. Is there something that is causing that? Any windows configuration or policy that does that every time that disk is plugged in on that specific machine?

Comment: Since this happens each time the disk is used at your *office*, it is properly an IT question. If you make a change that causes issues using the disk at work, the blame would be on you. Let IT fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, IT is not very competent on this case, need to figure a way to do fix it by myself

Comment: “When plugged in on office computer, the user on that computer takes ownership of that disk and when is plugged at home, it can be opened (Access is denied).“ - **What?**  Windows by default shouldn’t (doesn’t) require taking ownership of an external drive.  So if that’s happening, there is a good chance, that behavior is intentional.  You have permissions to plug an external drive in a work PC and a personal home PC?  The default permissions of an external non-system drive by default allows any user from any machine to access all files on it (unless the permissions are explicitly changed)